# How to count the value of a custom data types in lists?

Tags: java, list, collections, frequency

**I've seen something about hashMaps, but we haven't gotten that far in our work. Please keep your answers and helpful suggestions as simple as you can manage.**

I have a custom data type that is already made and works perfectly called Color. The only values of the type are Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, and Color.GREEN.

My task is to return Color.BLUE if there are more Color.BLUE in the list than the other colors, to return Color.RED if there are more Color.RED in the list than other colors, same for Color.GREEN and Color.YELLOW.

I have researched and and came up with this code:

```
public Color callColor(List<Card> hand) {

    int blueCards = Collections.frequency(hand, Color.BLUE);
    int redCards = Collections.frequency(hand, Color.RED);
    int greenCards = Collections.frequency(hand, Color.GREEN);
    int yellowCards = Collections.frequency(hand, Color.YELLOW);
    Color changeColorTo = Color.NONE;

    if ((blueCards > redCards) || (blueCards > greenCards) || (blueCards > yellowCards)) {
        changeColorTo = Color.BLUE;
    }

    if ((redCards > blueCards) || (redCards > greenCards) || (redCards > yellowCards)) {
        changeColorTo = Color.RED;
    }

    if ((greenCards > redCards) || (greenCards > blueCards) || (greenCards > yellowCards)) {
        changeColorTo = Color.GREEN;
    }

    if ((yellowCards > redCards) || (yellowCards > greenCards) || (yellowCards > blueCards)) {
        changeColorTo = Color.YELLOW;
    }
    return changeColorTo;
}
```

but this code causes blueCards, redCards, greenCards, and yellowCards all to be 0 when they should definitely not be zero.

So, in this case, my `Collections` implementation did not work at all. Help!

Comment: how are you making `List<Card> hand` ?

Comment: @Sanjeev I'm not sure. That part of the code was provided for us.

Comment: Can you post code of `Color` class ?

Comment: Use `switch` and calculate frequencies yourself.

Comment: @hattic iterate through your list and match color of a Card with individual Colors you have

Comment: @Sanjeev Color data type is just `public enum Color { RED, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, NONE }`

Comment: @Sanjeev Okay, so how could you do the syntax for the `Color` of a `Card`?

 I have this so far to start the iteration `public Color callColor(List<Card> hand) {
        
        for (int i = 0;i < hand.size(); i++) {
            
        }
        
        
        return`

Comment: If you can't tell us how to get the `Color` of a `Card` who should then? We don't have access to the `Card` class to take a look.

Comment: @MarkusBenko I'm still new to computer science so I don't fully understand what information i need to give to have people be able to give suggestions. trying my best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a `List<Card>` to the method, but then you're searching for the frequency of a certain `Color` in that list. That's why all counts are equal to 0.

Comment: We were provided with `public Color callColor(List<Card> hand) {` and were told to write the code underneath. How should I edit this?

Comment: If you're using Java 8, you can use `int blueCards = hand.stream().filter(h -> Color.BLUE.equals(h.getColor())).count();` and so on

Answer (score 1):

Your input list contains cards not colors.

So the possible problem solve is to convert you card list to color list first:

```
hand.stream().map(Card::getColor).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As the result you will get the list of colors, so you can now use Collection.frequency on it, not on initial card list.

However there are plenty of other ways to solve your problem, like using another Collection.

Answer (score 0):

[`Collections#frequency`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-) looks up occurrence of passed object in given collection but in your case you want to match on an attribute of collection of cards. That's why it gives you `0` for every frequency calculation.

Following is an iterative way of finding out card count for each color

```
for(Card card:hand) {

  if(card color is equal to Color.Blue) blueCards++
  else if(card color is equal to Color.Red) redCards ++

  // same code for other colors
}
```

Comment: Glad that helped you :)